# Сделать из одномерного списка двумерный список каждые n элементов

Tags: python, pandas, list, url, numpy

я читаю из огромного файла id и хочу через каждые 400 элементов делать из одномерного списка двумерный,но код никак не хочет работать.
Не подскажите в чем проблема?
Заранее благодарен.

```
import json
import itertools
import requests
import pandas as pd
def get_product_data():
   # Читаем айдишники из файла в один большой список
   with open('id.json', 'r') as file:
       ids = [line.strip() for line in file]
   # Делаем из одномерного списка двумерный список каждые n элементов
   count = 400
   ids = [ids[n:n + count] for n in range(0, len(ids), count)]
   # Отправляем GET и получаем результат
   result = []
   for group in ids:
       payload_data = {'product_ids': ' '.join(group)}
       f = requests.get('https://example.com/get?', params=payload_data)
       if f.status_code == 200:
           print('Good')
       if 'json' in f.headers['content-type']:
           print('Very Good')
       result.append(f.json())
       d = f.json()
   return d
#разбор словарь получаемых данных
def flatten_dict(d):
   def expand(key, value):
       if isinstance(value, dict):
           return [ (key + '.' + k, v) for k, v in flatten_dict(value).items() ]
       else:
           return [ (key, value) ]
   items = [ item for k, v in d.items() for item in expand(k, v) ]
   return dict(items)
# формируем DataFrem
d = get_product_data()
data = d['data']
data = list(map(flatten_dict, data))
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df[["id","title","price","old_price","href","comments_amount","sell_status","category_id","mpath","tag.name","tag.priority"]])
```

Comment: Можете привести пример входных данных (12 значений) и  пример двух матриц размерности 2х3, которые вы хотите получить?

Comment: Какое это имеет отношение к двумерному списку? Можете уточнить суть вопроса?

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых число элементов во входном файле должно быть кратным числу столбцов, которые вы хотите получить в  выходной 2D матрице.

Пример с использованием Numpy:

```
import numpy as np

num_columns = 10

data = np.loadtxt(filename)
arr = data.reshape(-1, num_columns)
```